# Ansible YAML indentation

Tags: linux, ansible, yaml

How to highlight ansible indentation using vim or any other text editor?
I have tried https://github.com/k1LoW/emacs-ansible, but cant able to get highlighted

Comment: One confusion, did you mean "syntax highlight" or "indentation characters" (like spaces, tabs)?

Comment: Even after doing auto indent config in vim, sometimes there will be indentation errors, so I wanted to highlight the column in vim editor for indentation check